# x-editable price format issue

Tags: x-editable

i have an issue in x-editable plugin, how to display prices in correct format in x-editable ? i would like to get the values as in price format like xx,xxx.xx ?

My code is

var editVehiclePrice = function (el, options) {

```
    var options = $.extend(true, {
        url: Utils.siteUrl() + 'dashboard/sell_vehicle/inline_vehicle_edit/',
        ajaxOptions: {
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        mode: 'inline',
    }, options || {
            params: function(params) {
                params.veh_id = $(this).data('vehid');
                return params;
            },
            success: function(response, newValue) {
                if(response.status == 0) return response.msg;
                console.log(Utils.numberFormat(newValue,2));
                $(response.to_update).text(newValue);
            },
            validate: function(value) {
                if($.trim(value) == '') {
                    return 'This field is required';
                }
            }
    });

    $(el).editable(options);
}
```

That console.log will display correct format value..but when i update it displays number in normal format..  Please help me

Answer (score 2):

if we want to display any changes after editing, we should add

```
             display: function(value, response) {
                var k = Utils.numberFormat(value,2);
                $(this).text(k);
             },
```

The price will display in the number format.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Anju's reply,

```
Utils.numberFormat(value,2);
```

is not defined. you can replace that with

```
 number.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+.)/g, '$1,');
```

or wrap it into a utility function